# How do I select all elements of a list, except one named item

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select all elements of a list, except the one whose ID is user-data, but this seems to exclude all elements.  What am I missing?

```
$('.menu li li:not(#user-data)').click(function () {});
```

DOM Structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="user-data" id="user-data"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have li in your li ?

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing the DOM structure.

Comment: It's probable OP needs `$('.menu li:not(#user-data)')`.

Comment: @dystroy, you are correct, that does the job.

Comment: Seems like SO gets infested with anon downvoters at weekends. Anyway I did +1 for the question update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this :

```
$('.menu li:not(#user-data)')
```

You were looking for a `li` element inside a `li` element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did not realize I was accidentally attempting to selecting a child.

Answer (score 0):

You can do next create new div with class wich will hold just part of menu which you want to select . For example

```
   <div class="menu">
     <div class="select">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home1</li>
        <li>Home2</li>
     </ul>
         </div>
     <div id="user-data"> ..... </div>
   </div>
```

Then your jquery will look like

```
$('.select ul li').click(function(){ .... 
      // body  )};
```